# Return a pointer from the function

Tags: c++, pointers

I was just looking for a correct syntax to return a pointer from the function and got surprised.

The search produced a lot of code like this:

```
int *A::foo()
{
    int b = ;
    int *c = &b;
    return c;
}
```

However, I believe that this code won't work as 'c' is a local variable and will be destroyed when it will go out of scope.

So, what is the proper way of returning the pointer from the function? The code like this:

```
void A::foo(int *ptr)
{
    ptr = 5 + ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    A a;
    a.foo( b );
}
```

So where I am wrong?

EDIT1:

I just tried the code suggested by Aiman, and it works. Which means that simple (standard) type works.

However, I need to make following code work:

```
SQLWCHAR *CODBCConfigure::ConvertFromString(const wxString &str)
{
    SQLWCHAR *string = new SQLWCHAR[str.length() * sizeof( SQLWCHAR )];
    string = const_cast<SQLWCHAR *>( str.wc_str() );
    SQLWCHAR *ret = string;
    return ret;
}
```

Trying to execute this code I see that the ret pointer still points to the proper address but the value there becomes wrong.

EDIT2:

Here is my latest code:

```
SQLWCHAR *tmp = const_cast<SQLWCHAR *>( str.wc_str() );
SQLWCHAR *string = new SQLWCHAR[sizeof( tmp ) * sizeof( SQLWCHAR )];
memcpy( string, tmp, sizeof( tmp ) );
return string;
```

Unfortunately this code also fails. The string pointer does not contain proper data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what about “the code like this”? You gave that snippet of code and asked where you’re wrong, but I don’t understand where the snippet of code you last gave fits in.

Comment: In your first snippet, the problem is that `b` would go out of scope and get automatically destroyed; `c` would get destroyed too, but that isn't the problem. The reason is you return `b`'s address not `c`'s. So when the code outside this function tries to access `b`, it'll no longer be alive, leading to the problem.

Comment: If you want the function to modify the caller's variable, use a reference. Pointers are for C, not C++.

Comment: The point I tried to make is that the first code snippet is wrong and one solution is to use a second snippet.

Comment: Also, I need to return SQLWCHAR * from the C++ function. And I'm passing in std::string. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
void A::foo(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 5 + *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 5;
    A a;
    a.foo( &b );
}
```

Whenever you're collecting a pointer, make sure you pass the address and not the variable itself, The pointer demands an address and not a value, and you need to update the value which the pointer is referencing, you were just trying to increment the pointer itself.

Comment: well the line "int b = 5;" should actually be "int *b = 5;" We are talking about pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on returning a pointer to something which will persist to exist even outside the function's scope, then dynamically allocate your number:

```
int *A::foo()
{
    int *b;
    b = new int(5);
    int *c = b;
    return c;
}
```

Put in mind that you will need to delete `b` yourself afterwards with `delete pointer_variable`.

If you don't care, then I suggest passing the value by reference:

```
//ampers and means ptr will be 'passed by reference'
void A::foo(int &ptr) //so changing ptr now changes the variable you passed itself
{
    ptr = 5 + ptr; // it isn't a pointer anymore, so better call it "ref"
}
```

Edit:

```
SQLWCHAR *CODBCConfigure::ConvertFromString(const wxString &str)
{
    SQLWCHAR *string = new SQLWCHAR[str.length() * sizeof( SQLWCHAR )];
    string = const_cast<SQLWCHAR *>( str.wc_str() );
    SQLWCHAR *ret = string;
    return ret;
}
```

1-Don't name your variables something like `string` because this can cause conflicts. e.g: In your case, if you're including the `<string>` header and `using namespace std;`.

2-You're redefining `string` immediately after assigning it something the second time, which is pointless. Much worse, it will cause a memory leak because you've allocated that memory in the first line and didn't free it (anything allocated with `new` needs to be freed using `delete').

3-Never take a pointer of what a function returns because when you do, you're taking the pointer of a temporary variable that was created on the fly and will be freed the moment you leave that line. You should assign it to a permanent memory location allocated by `new` first, and since what you're copying is essentially an array, you will need to copy the whole thing. I am not familiar with `SQLWCHAR` or wstrings in general, but something like `memcopy` can help you. Try this:

```
SQLWCHAR *CODBCConfigure::ConvertFromString(const wxString &str)
{
    SQLWCHAR *ret = new SQLWCHAR[str.length() * sizeof( SQLWCHAR )];
    SQLWCHAR *tmp = str.wc_str();
    memcopy(ret, temp, sizeof(tmp)); //probably str.length()+1 is what you need        
    //SQLWCHAR *ret = string; this line is redundant
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I actually don't. Solution 1 is good but it needs extra variable. And in solution 2 the caller is (pseudocode): [code] int *b = 5; A a; a.foo( b ); [/code]

Comment: also I just tried the solution 1 on MSVC 2010 with Win 8.1 and it does not work. On the return the pointer "*c" is not valid. It is a local variable to A::foo() and this is exactly the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @igor An extra variable? You really only need one variable; either you pass it as a parameter or create it in the function itself. I've just tried to change the least I could from the first member function you posted and make it work. Regarding the ""*c" is not valid", of course trying to access "c" from outside the function won't work, because the point itself will go out of scope, and that is exactly why we're returning the pointer. So what you do is `int * c = AObject.foo();` and `c`, or whatever you put in its place, will contain the pointer to 5.

Comment: please see my edit. An example with "int" works, but for some reason when I change int to "SQLWCHAR" the value becomes invalid.

Comment: please see my latest edit. BTW, there is no memcopy() function - it is named memcpy()..

Answer (score 0):

You overrides ptr of allocated memory by

```
SQLWCHAR *string = new SQLWCHAR[str.length() * sizeof( SQLWCHAR )];
```

then

```
string = const_cast<SQLWCHAR *>( str.wc_str() );
```

Use loop to copy characters from string or some different approach.